# Copy files from Linux to Windows 3.11 using parallel port

Tags: linux, networking, parallel-port, windows-3.1

How can I copy files from a Linux machine to one running Windows 3.11 or DOS 6.22 using the LPT (parallel) port? Do I need a cable with a special adapter?

I know I had this working a long time ago to share an internet connection via LPT from Windows XP to WfW 3.11. But I cant reproduce the setup. I google for about a few hours now.

Comment: What did you already try? Did you search on laplink (for the DOS part). Did you google on laptop and linux (either par or ser)?

Comment: I googles about 5 hours to get this solved. I know I once had a setup sharing the Internet connection via LPT from Windows XP to WfW 3.11. But I cant reproduce my setup.

Comment: You might want to add that to the question (using the [edit link](http://superuser.com/posts/987618/edit)). Without that it looks like a 'I did not do any work or research. Give me all the scriptz' question. And those tend to get closed fast.  As to the cable: You can use the serial port or the paralel (printer) port. The last has its pinout documented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LapLink_cable. (and while on that page, check out the 'see also' part).

Comment: Why do you need to surf the internet in Windows 3.11? Most pages won't be displayed properly

Comment: Why is that relevant?